# ProtoBuf from java application to web application

Tags: java, javascript, protocol-buffers

This is very new thing for me.
I am just wondering If we could send the ProtoBuf serialized data from java application to Web application (javascript) and de-serialize there. I am using TCP/IP connection in websocket to connect java application to javascript.
I have been looking at 
https://github.com/dcodeIO/ProtoBuf.js/
but they are using node.js ,which is not in my case.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

ProtoBuf.js also runs in the browser. Basically, all you have to do is to connect your client to your Java server using a (binary) WebSocket and to send ProtoBuf packets back and forth.

[Here is an example](https://github.com/dcodeIO/ProtoBuf.js/blob/master/examples/websocket/www/index.html) that decodes a message on the client side.